# python extend list by incremental values

Tags: python, list

Is there a nice simple method for extending a list *n* times, and doing so incrementally based on the existing values?

Basically I'm extrapolating a gradient, but don't want to invoke numpy/scipy if I can really avoid it.

I have some lists, lets say:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [10,20,30,40,50]
```

Where I have already got a value for the average of the pairwise differences (the 'average gradient' of the list). I would now like to extend each list (let's say 20 times, to a total length of 25 each), where each subsequent value added is the previous value plus the computed average difference (if this was negative, obviously it would decrease).

So, `x[5]` would evaluate to `x[4] + gradient`.

Thus, the `x` list would ultimately end up:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]
```

Because the average difference in the original `x` = 1 (obviously this is just test data, in actuality I want to do this with more complicated floats in the `y` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
# Calculate your gradient, for simplicity I will just assign 1
# If the gradient has to change, calculate inside the loop
gradient = 1
for i in range(20):
    x.append(x[-1] + gradient)
```

Comment: I had even gotten as far as `for i in range()`: x.append` - just couldn't engage the brain cells this morning! Thanks. I'll accept this as it was closest to what I was planning to do anyway

Answer (score 4):

You could use `list.extend()` and a generator expression:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> gradient, n = x[1]-x[0], 10
>>> x.extend(x[-1] + gradient for _ in range(1, n+1))
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

For lists of integers you can also pass a [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) to `list.extend()`:

```
>>> x.extend(range(x[-1]+gradient, x[-1] + gradient*n + 1, gradient))
```

Comment: `range()` does not support floats, so this answer would be better by dropping the second half and using `gradient` in the first half. Also, `extend()` will take a generator expression, so you don't need the inner `[]`.